# browser.declarativeNetRequest property is undefined despite processing static DNR redirects

Tags: javascript, typeerror, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am attempting to add dynamic DNR redirects to a MV3 web extension running in Firefox 123. When the script in charge of adding dynamic redirects runs, it throws the error `TypeError: can't access property "updateDynamicRules", browser.declarativeNetRequest is undefined`. However, if I add a static redirect via the `declarative_net_request` property in the extension's `manifest.json`, it redirects the network requests exactly as expected.

The extension has the necessary permissions and host permissions needed to use the declaritiveNetRequest API, and attempts to add dynamic rules via the `declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules()` method in a content script.

`manifest.json`

```
"permissions": [ "storage", "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess" ],
"host_permissions": ["*://*.example.com/"],
```

content script

```
await browser.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
  removeRuleIds: oldIds,
  addRules: newRules,
});
```

Comment: Most of API in `browser` or `chrome` cannot be used in a content script. Do it in the background script.